# Move image from public:// to folder inside module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, file-move

i want to move a uploaded file locate in public:// to a folder inside mymodule.

I try

```
$dirname = dirname(__file__);
$fullpath = strpos($dirname, '\\') === false ? $dirname . '/' . $file->filename : $dirname . '\\' . $file->filename;
$go = file_move($file, $fullpath);
```

and i got this error

```
The specified file public://xxx.BMP could not be moved, because the destination is invalid. More information is available in the system log.
```

But de $destination is valid and is mymodule's folder!!

Can anyone helpme to move-it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, moving files to the module folder isn't good idea.
But, if you want to do this, use path, relative to drupal root or absolute file path.
Also, check folder permission for your module's directory (by default, module folders is read-only).
If this not helps, i recommend you to check system log for more detailed error explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Best is to move the files in public://

```
$dest = 'public://';
$file = file_move($file, $dest)
```

Comment: Although files should be saved to and served from public:// The question was asking for the opposite.